# StreamCorruptedException when Serializing and encrypting ArrayList object

Tags: java, encryption, serialization, arraylist

I'm trying to get the encrypted data in my file. But i get a java.io.StreamCorruptedException.
Following is my code

```
public ArrayList<FootballClub> FootBallInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
File file = new File("FootballClub.ser");
fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);

SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(fileIn, cipher);
in = new ObjectInputStream(cipherIn);

SealedObject sealed = (SealedObject) in.readObject();

ArrayList<FootballClub> e = (ArrayList<FootballClub>) sealed.getObject(cipher);

in.close();

fileIn.close();

return e;

}
public void FootBallOutputStream(ArrayList<FootballClub> e) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

File file = new File("FootballClub.ser");
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);


SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
Cipher cipher = (Cipher.getInstance("AES"));
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
SealedObject sealed = new SealedObject(e, cipher);

CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fileOut, cipher);
out = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOut);
out.writeObject(sealed);
out.close();
fileOut.close();
}
```

My exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: CF8CA0C1
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
    at premierleague.controller.Serializing.FootBallInputStream(Serializing.java:54)
```

Please help me with this exception. I've been trying to solve this for almost 24 hours. I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You're encrypting and decrypting twice, with the Cipher streams and the SealedObjects. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different keys. You need to use the same key for decryption as for encryption.